# Obtener el TXT de un archivo zip Descargado

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola hay un archivo en [internet](http://www.sunat.gob.pe/descarga/BueCont/BueCont_TXT.zip) que es un zip que contiene un txt, y es el archivo que quiero obtener, estoy usando Python 3.7.2 y este es mi código:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO

url = "http://www.sunat.gob.pe/descarga/BueCont/BueCont_TXT.zip"
response = urlopen(url)
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(response.read()))
file = zip.read('BueCont_TXT.txt')
datos = str(file)
print(datos) #Datos convertido a String
```

Pero me imprime el texto con caracteres extraños

> b'Ruc|Nombre/Razon|A partir del|Resolucion|\r20552103816|AGROLIGHT
>   PERU S.A.C.|01/09/2017|RS 0230050199217|\r20549500553|ASERCO EB
>   EMPRESA INDIVIDUAL DE RESPONSABILIDAD LIMITADA|01/02/2017|RS
>   0230050178480|\r20553856451|BI GRAND CONFECCIONES S.A.C.|01/08/2015|RS
>   0230050136038|\r20506988749|BIOLATIN E.I.R.L|01/08/2015|RS
>   0230050132461|.....

Buscando encontre cosas como que tengo que decodificarlo a 'utf-8':

```
file.decode("utf-8")
```

pero me arrojaba un error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position
>   5221: invalid continuation byte - - -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que obtienes tras leer el archivo zip, en la variable `file`, es un string de bytes. Tienes que convertirlo a un string de caracteres.

Tu intento: `datos = str(file)` debería especificar qué *encoding* usa la secuencia de bytes, para poder convertirlo a caracteres. Al no especificar ese parámetro, python se limita a retornar su forma "representable", que es la que ves al imprimirlo. La variable `datos` es en realidad esto:

```
"b'Ruc|Nombre/Razon|A p.....'"
```

Y además, cada caracter que no sea ASCII se representa mediante una secuencia de escape que comienza por `\`. Así por ejemplo, tus datos contienen bytes con el valor 13, para separar una línea de otra, lo cual se muestra como `\r`, y algún otro byte que no está claro qué letra representaría, que se representa mediante `\xd1`, lo que significa que es un byte cuyo valor es en hexadecimal `d1`.

Hay dos cosas que corregir en esa secuencia de bytes:

- Para separar líneas usa `\r` en  lugar de `\n`. Esto no es muy habitual hoy día. El uso de `\r` como separador de líneas era típico en los antiguos Mac. Hoy día tanto Mac como Linux usan `\n`. En Windows se usa la secuencia `\r\n`.

  Corregir esto es muy sencillo, un simple `.replace("\r", "\n")` servirá
- Los bytes como `\xd1` deben convertirse al carácter que representan. Esto es más difícil ya que no sabemos de antemano qué caracter representan si no sabemos con qué codificación fue generado el fichero. Tú has intentado `"utf_8"`, pero no ha funcionado porque un byte `\xd1` no es válido como parte de un texto UTF-8 (a menos que vaya precedido de otro byte especial, lo que no era el caso). La codificación es otra.

  Bastante probablemente la codificación "windows1252", pues en esa codificación los "caracteres raros" que se observan (`"\xd1"` y otros similares) representarían vocales acentuadas, eñes, y u con diéresis (aunque también aparecen caracteres más sospechosos, como el símbolo del yen).

Suponiendo que sea efectivamente "windows1252" propongo la siguiente forma de leer tu archivo:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO

url = "http://www.sunat.gob.pe/descarga/BueCont/BueCont_TXT.zip"
response = urlopen(url)
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(response.read()))
file = zip.read('BueCont_TXT.txt')
datos = file.decode("windows-1252")
datos = datos.replace("\r", "\r\n")
```

Tras esto, los 200 primeros caracteres y los 200 últimos se ven así:

```
>>> print(datos[:200])
Ruc|Nombre/Razon|A partir del|Resolucion|
20552103816|AGROLIGHT PERU S.A.C.|01/09/2017|RS 0230050199217|
20549500553|ASERCO EB EMPRESA INDIVIDUAL DE RESPONSABILIDAD LIMITADA|01/02/2017|RS 0230050178

>>> print(datos[-200:])
671|
20600455681|ÑUGAY E.I.R.L.|01/02/2017|RS 0230050183259|
20601472296|ÑUXTU DIGITAL BUSINESS E.I.R.L.|01/09/2018|RS 0530050027642|
10428290556|ÑUÑONCCA PUMA ANDREA|01/09/2017|RS 0530050023616|
```

Lo que probablemente sea correcto (aunque no sé yo esos nombres con eñes...)

### Addenda

Para determinar que la codificación más probable era "windows-1252" use dós técnicas:

La biblioteca `chardet` analiza una secuencia de bytes y usa una serie de heurísticos para decidir cuál es su codificación. Usándola se obtiene:

```
import chardet
print(chardet.detect(file))
```

Tarda un ratillo, pues el fichero es grande, y al final dice:

```
{'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'language': '', 'confidence': 0.7291544870994111}
```

La probabilidad del 72.9% es un poco baja, pero ha decidido que es Windows-1252.

Por si acaso, eché un vistazo a todos los caracteres no-ascii que había en la secuencia, probando a decodificarlos como Windows-1252 o como iso-8859-1, pues son dos encodings casi idénticos salvo en unos pocos caracteres:

```
d = {}
for letra in file:
  if letra>128:
    d[letra] = (bytes([letra]).decode("iso-8859-1"),
                bytes([letra]).decode("windows-1252"))
```

y obtuve:

```
{145: ('\x91', '‘'),
 146: ('\x92', '’'),
 165: ('¥', '¥'),
 168: ('¨', '¨'),
 176: ('°', '°'),
 180: ('´', '´'),
 186: ('º', 'º'),
 193: ('Á', 'Á'),
 195: ('Ã', 'Ã'),
 196: ('Ä', 'Ä'),
 201: ('É', 'É'),
 202: ('Ê', 'Ê'),
 204: ('Ì', 'Ì'),
 205: ('Í', 'Í'),
 209: ('Ñ', 'Ñ'),
 210: ('Ò', 'Ò'),
 211: ('Ó', 'Ó'),
 214: ('Ö', 'Ö'),
 218: ('Ú', 'Ú'),
 219: ('Û', 'Û'),
 220: ('Ü', 'Ü'),
 233: ('é', 'é'),
 237: ('í', 'í'),
 241: ('ñ', 'ñ'),
 252: ('ü', 'ü')}
```

Donde vemos que todos los caracteres "raros" hallados, al final se decodifican de la misma forma tanto con Windows-1252 como con iso-8859-1, excepto los dos primeros que son una especie de apóstrofe en Windows-1252 pero son caracteres no representables en iso-8859-1. Por eso me decido yo también por Windows-1252. También vemos algunos caracteres un tanto raros como el Yen. A lo mejor hay datos erróneos en ese fichero.

Answer (score 0):

No tiene caracteres extraños, cada `\r` te indica una nueva linea.
Haz un split para obtener linea por linea.

```
lineas = str(file).split("\r")
```

Comment: Los `\r` no lo reconoce con texto, sino lo trata como otra cosa, en concreto el \

Comment: Pues a mi si me lo hizo bien: `['Ruc|Nombre/Razon|A partir del|Resolucion|', '20552103816|AGROLIGHT PERU S.A.C.|01/09/2017|RS 0230050199217|', '20549500553|ASERCO EB EMPRESA !INDIVIDUAL DE RESPONSABILIDAD LIMITADA|01/02/2017|RS 0230050178480|', '20553856451|BI GRAND CONFECCIONES S.A.C.|01/08/2015|RS 0230050136038|']`